# What sort of switch does the Key have?

Tags: support, blog, fun, april-fools

The description of the [key](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste/) is described as

> Our click’s volume and tone were crafted by sampling the natural wonder of song bird chirps. We run that audio data through cutting edge deep learning systems to produce a sound that is optimized to improve productivity and mood.

Now while I love my cherry blues, their sound is harsh and mechanical. What sort of key does the key use, and will the clouds open up and shine one single ray at me if I type on it? Will I attract wildland animals like a Disney Princess? (Having a friendly bear and 200 squirrels turn up would be looked upon poorly at most workplaces)

Comment: I have to say, I was fooled for a minute or two. Then I reread the article and looked at the date ;)

Comment: _“Having a friendly bear and 200 squirrels turn up would be looked upon poorly at most workplaces”_ — Not to mention the song they would start singing.

Comment: It might be... Unbearable

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Naturally, it is one of the latest advancements in the keyboard industry - a **B**iodegradable **A**dvanced **I**ntegrated **T**echnology switch that allows us to achieve the unparalleled sound and performance you can only get from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yep. It's the best BAIT ever!